# How to create a star triangle with an odd pattern that increases by 2?

Tags: python

I have looked everywhere and have tried to combine methods, but nothing has gotten me the result I am interested in.
I am trying to create a right triangle with a star pattern that starts at 1 and increases by 2, as shown here:

[image]

Comment: tried `loop` ? `while` with a initial variable `1` then increase it by `1`. Also `'*' * 5 = '*****'`

Comment: Can you show some code that you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(1, 100, 2):
 print("*" * i)
```